# How to change the color of the certain breadcrumb element using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, breadcrumbs

I would like to change the color of the breadcrumb element.

Example one: https://www.travellaggio.com/product-category/italy/mantova/
Example two: https://www.travellaggio.com/mantova/10674

All arrows (I use Font Awesome icons for them) excluding the last one should be in grey color. But now all arrows are white and I can't separate them by color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/* target chevron inside the header that are not the last one */
.entry-title .fa-chevron-right:not(:last-of-type) {
    color: #777777;
}
```

Tested in chrome dev tools:
[image]